# Syntax Error Issue on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract some values using VBA from a Website

The following code contains the array of the data I am looking for. This works perfectly and gives me the array of the data I am looking for.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).querySelectorAll("[class$='price']")
```

The result for the above is

```
<NodeList length="23">...</NodeList>
```

But when I am trying to extract the values by running the loop in a VBA by using the following code

```
lnth = document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).querySelectorAll("[class$='price']").Length - 1

For x = 0 To lnth

    firstResult = document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).querySelectorAll("[class$='price']")(x).innerText

Next x
```

The code would give error at firstResult since it would not get any value. I checked on Internet Explorer there is no value if I use "(" brackets,however if I use "[" on Internet Explorer it works but VBA would not accept "[" Brackets.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).querySelectorAll("[class$='price']")[0]
```

The code above works on Internet Explorer Console but cant be used in VBA.

I am sure I am missing something would be of great help if you can advice what is the workaround on this.

[image]

Comment: When you enter the command in the IE Console you are using Javascript, not VBA.

Comment: Can you share the source url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the innerText, you can use `getElementsByClassName` 2 more times, one of them inside `for each .. next` loop since your values are in `list-flights -> price -> cash js_linkInsideCell`:

```
Set priceData = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).getElementsByClassName("price")

For Each Item In priceData
    Debug.Print Item.getElementsByClassName("cash js_linkInsideCell")(0).innerHTML
Next Item
```

Using `.querySelectorAll("[class$='price']")` works as well, but it crashes IE object after parsing. Try and see if it crashes:

```
Set priceData = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).querySelectorAll("[class$='price']")

For Each Item In priceData
    Debug.Print Item.getElementsByClassName("cash js_linkInsideCell")(0).innerHTML
Next Item
```

**Some quick notes:**

1-You can use this code to wait for IE object to load url:

```
Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
```

2-Sometimes, even if IE object is ready, query results are not returned that fast. This means the elements you are looking for are not ready yet and do not exists so you get an error message:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

To avoid this message my workaround is as follows:

```
Do
On Error Resume Next
Set priceData = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("list-flights")(0).getElementsByClassName("price")
Loop Until Err.Number <> 91
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I also realised it, that this does not work with querySelector, but works with ClassName. Thanks your efforts. Cheers !

Comment: @Blue Moon Glad to help.

Comment: BTW your loop method with Error91 is something new which I learnt. I had tried so many things to check this scenario, but this method is awesome. Truly you are gifted. !

Comment: @ Tehscript I changed all the Err91 to your new codes, and I am amazed how perfectly this code runs. I have seen lot of forums on people asking about foolproof method, but this one is the find of the decade for me !