# How can I get to the bottom of a webpage rectifying the existing loop?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script using vba in combination with selenium to get to the bottom of a lazy-loading webpage. However, my script is able to do that. But the for x loop I've used in my script is looking weird and I've no explanation for it. What I expect to do is use the same loop without any number hardcoded to it, as in 200 in this case. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

```
Sub Get_links()
Dim driver As New WebDriver

With driver
    .Start "chrome", "http://fortune.com/fortune500"
    .get "/list/"
End With

For x = 0 To 200
    driver.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"
    driver.Wait 500
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I really like solving/adapting your questions, they are really challenging. Here you go:

```
Sub Get_links()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim CurrentPageHeight As Long, PrevPageHeight As Long
Dim EndofPage As Boolean

'EndofPage = False
With driver
    .Start "chrome", "http://fortune.com/fortune500"
    .get "/list/"
End With

Do While EndofPage = False
    PrevPageHeight = CurrentPageHeight
    CurrentPageHeight = driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var CurrentPageHeight=document.body.scrollHeight;return CurrentPageHeight;")
    driver.Wait 3000 'depending on your internet connection, increase or decrease time
    If PrevPageHeight = CurrentPageHeight Then
        EndofPage = True
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I suppose there is no implicit or explicit wait for Selenium in VBA, and there is no need to.

While scraping the web, whether it is Selenium or not, I always choose to rely on if element in page exists or not. From my personal experiences, "implicit and explicit wait" failed me both in python and vba while scraping.

Again, personally, I found that VBA is more reliable and easier than python not only for scraping but also for extracting data to excel since they in the same platform. The reason of this is because I found a solution to make sure I am scraping the page I want (not the previously loaded page in loop). Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704985/syntax-error-issue-on-vba/43706218#43706218) for the above mentioned solution which I was unable to find such a thing on the net.

I could implement the same thing to python, but I would do that only if I was going to use my parsed data in an api for example. Since it is excel, VBA is a better choice.

Anyways, I mimic-ed the implicit wait for you below. I hope it offers an insight into your comment/question.

```
Sub Get_links()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim CurrentPageHeight As Long, NextPageHeight As Long
Dim EndofPage As Boolean

'EndofPage = False
With driver
    .Start "chrome", "http://fortune.com/fortune500"
    .get "/list/"
End With

Do
driver.ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print Split(driver.FindElementsByClass("company-list")(1).Text, vbLf)(3001)
Loop Until Err.Number <> 9

End Sub
```

**Edit2:** The reason behind using `Debug.Print Split(driver.FindElementsByClass("company-list")(1).Text, vbLf)(3001)` is checking an element that belongs to the bottom of page, if it exists or not. There is nothing special about this phrase, you can use something similar as long as you can return an element from the bottom. Let me explain my logic:

If you debug.print `driver.FindElementsByClass("company-list")(1).Text`, you will see that is the complete list separated by line feeders.

So I split them with `vbLf` and have the rank `1000` in the list which is 3001st element. How do I know this? With a quick simple logic:

```
...(1).Text, vbLf)(0) -> RANK
...(1).Text, vbLf)(1) -> COMPANY
...(1).Text, vbLf)(2) -> REVENUES ($M)
...(1).Text, vbLf)(3) -> 1
...(1).Text, vbLf)(4) -> Walmart
...(1).Text, vbLf)(5) -> $485,873
...(1).Text, vbLf)(6) -> 2
.
.

(Rank 1) * 3 = (3)
(Rank 2) * 3 = (6)
.
.
.
(Rank 1000) * 3 = (3000)
```

You should have got rank `1000` from (3000), but you don't because there is another `div` right after 20th line in list. So it is (3001). You can use 3000, 2950, 2912, whatever you like as long as they are in the last 50 group.

Comment: You are really the gem of a guy, Tehscript. You have some set of skills which are hardly found in others. You should check out StackExchange site as well - a great place for vba giants. Btw, do you know if there is any option available for explicit wait in vba with selenium? Long live, Tehscript!!!

Comment: I was not around my PC so 've delayed to respond. I've got every piece of your code like bible. Your provided code just runs flawlessly fetching whatever the results might be. I wish I could get a teacher like you. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Btw, I'm little behind in understanding the (3001) index. Would you please help me understand what that is for? Excuse my ignorance. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 Sure, you will see it is nothing special when you read it. Please see my Edit2

Comment: What an elaborative description!! It helped me a lot to understand how things work. Highly indebted to you. Thanks once again for the clarity.

Comment: Hi @SIM. Ask it as a question and I will look into it. But I cannot promise if I can be of assistance or not.